# Windows Forms Designer - automatically adds namespace in front of class

Tags: c#, winforms, namespaces, windows-forms-designer

I have problem with Visual Studio Designer.

When I display design of a form, designer automatically adds namespace in front of class, which is used as datasource.
But this class is in the same namespace as the form.

It is annoying.

**Example:**

```
namespace Editor
{
    partial class AddSignalForm
    {
      ...
      this.signalsBS.DataSource = typeof(Signal);

    }
}
```

Signal is in namespace `Editor`.

But after I open designer, code is changed to:

```
namespace Editor
{
    partial class AddSignalForm
    {
      ...
      this.signalsBS.DataSource = typeof(Editor.Signal);

    }
}
```

Problem is that compiler can not find class `Editor.Editor.Signal`.

Comment: Are you editing code generated by the designer? You shouldn't do that.

Comment: If this is a form then the designer file and the code file for the form must have the same namespace.

Comment: No, I didnt changed designer code. Designer file and code file are in the same namespace. But when I change (using designer) DataSource of signalsBS (BindingSource) to Signal type, designer will generate wrong code. I can't compile that  code, so I have to change code in designer file :/.

Comment: Do you need to qualify the use of Signal then - what namespace does signal sit in?

Comment: Signal is in the same namespace as designer file. It is in namespace Editor.

Comment: You seem to have another class or property named `Editor` which conflicts with the namespace.

Comment: @julien You are right. Omg.So stupid thing. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: @JulienLebosquain please post your comment as an answer, and Michal please accept if/when he does

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have another class or property named `Editor` which conflicts with the namespace.

Comment: I had the same problem. You helped me notice what's wrong! In my case I had naively started with a class the name of which was the same as the containing namespace. What I learn from it is that this is not a good idea because the designer sees a name ambiguity where the language itself does not.

Comment: Also check to see that you have not inadvertently added the "namespace  Editor {" snippet into a file twice (nested two of them). That will cause this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

For any others who have this problem....
I discovered that in one file, I had inadvertently put the namespace declaration in the code file twice:

as in :

```
namespace MyCompany.MyApplication
{
     namespace MyCompany.MyApplication
     {
          //class definitions
     }
}
```

This caused the designer to mess up and add the namespace to the name in the Binding Source DataSource.