# Why does Visual Studio append the namespace to the name of a user control when adding it to the designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I have a user control named `Editor` that is part of the `StackCustomWindow` namespace. The `StackCustomWindow` namespace contains the main form for the program. When I add the `Editor` user control to the main window using the designer, Visual Studio 2010 places code like this in the designer:

```
this.editor1 = new StackCustomWindow.Editor();
```

when it should just be this:

```
this.editor1 = new Editor();
```

Compiling throws an exception:

> Error 1   The type name 'Editor' does not exist in the type
>
> 'StackCustomWindow.StackCustomWindow' C:\Users\ricardo\Documents\Visual Studio
>
> 2010\Projects\StackCustomWindow\StackCustomWindow\StackCustomWindow.Designer.cs   35  51  StackCustomWindow

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300292/windows-forms-designer-automatically-adds-namespace-in-front-of-class), with a solution that said a duplicate name must exist somewhere in the solution, but a) I don't know why that would exist in this case, since I have no other controls with that name, and b) I don't know how to check if a duplicate name actually does exist. I don't have any other user controls or items named `Editor`, and Visual Studio does this for *all* of my user controls. As you can see below, all of the code is very basic, with no controls besides the user control and the main window.

Code for `Editor`:

using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace StackCustomWindow
{
    public partial class Editor : UserControl
    {
        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and it's `designer.cs` file:

```
namespace StackCustomWindow
{
    partial class Editor
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Editor
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Name = "Editor";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(452, 276);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

StackCustomWindow.cs:

using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace StackCustomWindow
{
    public partial class StackCustomWindow : Form
    {
        public StackCustomWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

StackCustomWindow.designer.cs:

```
namespace StackCustomWindow
{
    partial class StackCustomWindow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // StackCustomWindow
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(718, 535);
            this.Name = "StackCustomWindow";
            this.Text = "StackCustomWindow";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: There is an [Editor] attribute (full name EditorAttribute) - I don't suppose that could be causing problems could it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Forms Designer - automatically adds namespace in front of class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300292/windows-forms-designer-automatically-adds-namespace-in-front-of-class)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the StackCustomWindow Type is named the same as the StackCustomWindow namespace. So StackCustomWindow.Editor ends up being interpreted as "member 'Editor' of type StackCustomWindow", instead of "member 'Editor' of namespace StackCustomWindow".

Using a different name for the namespace and the type will prevent this problem.

Your code is valid, the code generated by the designer isn't. The code generator doesn't expect you to do what you did and doesn't handle it well.

Comment: It's interesting that Visual Studio doesn't warn you about this, but maybe it's because it's such an amateur mistake or such a warning could over-complicate matters (and yes, this fixes the problem).

Comment: @svinja you nailed it! the same occurs in VB .NET if you have for instance a project with a module declared using the same project's name. Like `AppGlobals.AppGlobals.vb`. VB users (not used to see Namespace declarations): change this namespace in Project Properties' first tab.

Comment: still encountering the same problem even in vs2017, instead of changing the name of the class, which had been used at multiple places I changed the namespace since mine was a much smaller project

Answer (score -1):

You may be clashing with the `System.Collections.Stack System.Collections.Generic.Stack` class. Are you using either of these namespaces (`System.Collections`, `System.Collections.Generic`)?

Comment: No, I'm not including either of those. I don't know why that would cause a conflict with Editor, though. If I rename `Stack` to `StackCustomWindow` I still have problems (I updated the question to reflect the name change).